Ssh connection freezes
I have a strange problem with my ssh connection on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
At some point after login it will not accept new ssh connections. Connection startup hangs at
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to rpibackup.lan:22 as 'pi'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
^C

In those cases I managed to connect with a different KexAlgorithm setting
ssh -o KexAlgorithms=curve25519-sha256  pi@rpibackup.lan

which lets me connect. However, commands like top will immediately freeze the connection, maybe even the process.
I figured that issuing an apt command also led to a freeze, but apparently after a new login the database was still locked.
First thought it's a problem with my sd card. So I bought a new one, did a fresh install and still the problem persists.

Sounds like the ssh daemon is crashing. Consider opening an Ubuntu bug with canonical.
